# is there anyway to check UINavigationBar Button clicked?

Tags: iphone

I use `UINavigationbar`, it works fine.

But now i have a paramater, which is global, to count the `pushUIViewController` for using `popToUIViewController` at index (index of screen i wanna be back). it worked but have an error when i click on `UINavigation` Left Button to get back to previous screen, this makes paramater continuing count (++).

then when i get back on the screen i expect the paramater had a different value.

How can I check if button of `UINavigationbar` is clicked or not???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add button manually on navigation bar:

```
 UIButton *titleButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[titleButton setTitle:@"myTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
titleButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 44);
titleButton.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
[titleButton addTarget:self action:@selector(titleTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleButton;
```

Add titleTap method to catch the tap event :

```
    - (IBAction) titleTap:(id) sender
{
    NSLog(@"Title tap");
}
```

Comment: i solved my problem by get index in array of pushUIViewcontroller in navigation. thanks for your reply. i consider this for later project.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(method:)];
cancelEdit:, the selector, is in the current class (self) and is defined as:

- (void) method: (id) sender
{
//use nslog to print string (or)perform any action to change view background colors;
nslog("click"):
(or)
self.view.backgroundcolor=[UIColor redcolor];
}
```